# Create .env file with shell script - how to wrap value in commas?

Tags: shell, sed, environment-variables

I am currently using the following to make a `.env` to help me with with my environment variables when using docker > supervisor > cron.

`printenv > /var/www/laravel.env`

This prints a list which is perfect (except issues with those with spaces in...)

I know that I can use `sed` to seperate them at the `=` sign and then wrap the second part in speech marks.

For example..

```
MY_VAR="MY VALUE WITH SPACES WORKS"
```

Comment: is it possible to show a bigger sample of your input and expected output (and what is your problem with space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
printenv | sed 's/\([^=]*=\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"/'
```

Comment: Perfect!, I'm really cr*p at xpath. Is your solution better than `printenv |awk -F"=" '{print $1"=""\""$2"\""}'` i can't tell the difference :/

Comment: As mentionned by poster, this `awk` will not work if `=` are present in values (eg: `LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:` will output `LS_COLORS="rs"`).

Comment: Just to confirm though, yours will?

Comment: Yes, the whole string after first `=` found will be quoted.

Comment: @SLePort your solution can be improved to support double quotes in the env values: `printenv | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | sed 's/\([^=]*=\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"/'`

Answer (score 2):

The output of `printenv` can't be used to reliably reconstruct the values of all possible environment variables. Consider this output:

```
foo=bar
baz=3
```

Is that the result of `export foo=bar baz=3` or `export foo=$'bar\nbaz=3'`? There is no way to know.

In fact, I do not know of a portable way to reproduce *any* valid environment so that it can be reconstructed. The closest thing I can think of is in `bash`, you can use `declare -px` to produce output which can be used as the target of a `source` command to reproduce values whose names are valid identifiers.

Comment: These are just static values required by my web app. It works fine except the spaces in it. Any idea on how to adjust output?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, unless the values contain also `=`

```
printenv |awk -F"=" '{print $1"=""\""$2"\""}'
```